# Ignoring space characters when linking tables

Tags: crystal-reports, report, spacing

I’m experiancing a problem when trying to link to tables in the database expert. The two fields that link the tables have exactly the same information except one table always has an additional space. For example;
Table 1 = Multivitamin/Tablets

Table 2 = Multivitamin//Tablets

- ‘/‘ are representing spaces

Formulas won’t help (e.g. extractstring etc) as it’s the tables themselves I need to link together

This is preventing me from retrieving the information I need. Any advice on how I can get around this?

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to come across this:

- Consider using a command as datasource instead of tables. When writing the query of the command you can define the join condition yourself.
- If you have access to the data source, you could add a calculated field to the tables to contain the normalized field values and then use these for linking in CR.
- Alternatively, one could create views in the database, either adding normalized "linking fields" or providing the joined tables results.
- If it's only a few rows in CR, you could consider using SQL fields or subreports to retrieve data from Table 2.